# Sending simple data from one device to another

Tags: android, device

I want to make a simple app that sends data from one device to another when both devices have installed the application.
Can you please tell me what the most simple way to do this is, I'd rather not use GCM or sockets.

Comment: data is send to another devices on what event?

Comment: i mean if u wanna send data to another device without gcm , then second device hv to fetch itself via service

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a server, register both devices to the server and send messages to one another through GCM.
This is the easiest solution, since you don't mess with exchanging credentials between devices.

One more solution would be to exchange messages using GCM, but without having a server. In such case, you should add your GCM server key to every device and send the messages to Google directly from the device, then Google will deliver your messages.
You should exchange keys in another way, i.e. using email, so that both devices have each others key.
This is both **unsafe** and hard to synchronize though.

Since you do not want to use GCM, your possibilities are limited since you have to somehow implement the whole synchronization yourself.
An easy case for this one would be to use Bluetooth, so that you can easily exchange messages in a paired device which is near by.

I can't think of another way on how you could accomplish that, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a short message, you might be able to use sms text messaging.  I did this in an app at one point, but then Google announced that KitKat would be changing the way sms messages worked so I migrated to GCM.